# Disassemble all functions with radare2

Tags: radare2

The `pdf` command is able to disassemble a function in radare2. Is there a way to disassemble all functions of a binary in a single radare2 command ?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over functions (or anything else) using `@@` command modifier.

In your case, after you analyze the binary to get functions, you can run:

```
pdf @@ fcn*
```

This command will print the disassembly of every function iterating over function's flags starting with *fcn*. You can use any other wildcard you want.

You might also want to check out `pdr` (`pdr.`) command, which prints disassembly recursively across the function graph (form current basic block)

Comment: There could be some functions which don't have "fcn" in their names.